Are all PE sections loaded to the same base address in memory? If not, how does PIC code find data in other sections?
Are all PE sections loaded to the same base address in memory? If not, how does PIC code find data in other sections?
For example, let's say I have code such as:
.text
   mov rax, myData
.data
   myData: ...

For the code to be PIC, the mov must use relative addressing.  I understand how this works if VA(.data) - FileOffset(.data) == VA(.text) - FileOffset(.text).  Is that guaranteed by the Windows PE loader? If not, how would PIC code like the above find the relative address to myData?

When a DLL or EXE is loaded in Windows (or UEFI), the operating system selects a base address for the program's memory mapping.  All memory addresses within the program--global variables, functions--get positioned relative to this base address, called the "image base" in Win32 documentation.
PE sections are also loaded at an offset to this image base.  Here is an example from Windows notepad.exe, using dumpbin /headers:
SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
    92A8 virtual size
   26000 virtual address (0000000140026000 to 000000014002F2A7)
    9400 size of raw data
   24A00 file pointer to raw data (00024A00 to 0002DDFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

When loaded into memory, the contents of Notepad's .rdata section get loaded to image_base + 0x26000.
Because every section is relative to the same image base address, the distance between any two points anywhere in the loaded image is always a constant.
Note: The distance between any two points in the same image being constant is only true for loaded images.  On disk, PE files often omit empty space, and there are alignment considerations.
Now back to the assembly code you have.  The code you wrote is not position-independent.  When you write it like that, there will be runtime fixups--"relocation"--applied to make the reference to myData work.  A better example would be to use x86-64's RIP-relative addressing mode:
.text
   lea rax, [myData]
.data
   myData: ...

This gets translated by the assembler to lea rax, [rip + ???].  The linker fills this in, with ??? becoming the distance between myData and the lea instruction (actually, the address of the instruction immediately after).
Because such distances are constant, this instruction in the DLL becomes hardcoded and does not need to be relocated.
Modern operating systems' program loaders all work this way, with OS-specific quirks.
